# How to fix the Duet AI "Client is not running" error on Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

Sometimes I find that Duet AI gets messed up on Google Cloud Shell IDE (using the new VS Code one, not legacy) and one of the opaque errors it gives is "Client is not running":

[image: Client is not running error from Duet AI]

How do I *run the client* for Duet AI to get it working again? Is there a command or tool of some kind in Google Cloud Shell that can be used to reset it when it's gotten broken?

---

Here is a snip from the Output panel of Duet AI (some call stacks that might be helpful ):

```
[Error - 6:53:33 PM] Server initialization failed.
Error: command '_cloudcode.duetAI.ls.completionAccepted' already exists
    at n.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:125:82889)
    at Object.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:20485)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.register (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12865347)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.initialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12864926)
    at A.initializeFeatures (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12815447)
    at A.doInitialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12802261)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
    at async A.start (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12799276)
[Error - 6:53:33 PM] Duet AI client: couldn't create connection to server.
Error: command '_cloudcode.duetAI.ls.completionAccepted' already exists
    at n.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:125:82889)
    at Object.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:20485)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.register (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12865347)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.initialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12864926)
    at A.initializeFeatures (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12815447)
    at A.doInitialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12802261)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
    at async A.start (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12799276)
[Error - 6:53:33 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didOpen failed
Error: command '_cloudcode.duetAI.ls.completionAccepted' already exists
    at n.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:125:82889)
    at Object.registerCommand (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:20485)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.register (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12865347)
    at t.ExecuteCommandFeature.initialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12864926)
    at A.initializeFeatures (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12815447)
    at A.doInitialize (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12802261)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
    at async A.start (/google/devshell/editor/code-oss-for-cloud-shell/extensions/cloudcode/dist/extension.js:8:12799276
```

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for this report.  Could you please submit this as "feedback" from the IDE UI as it will collect additional logs to help diagnose the problem.  Click on "Duet AI" in the status bar, then select "Send feedback."  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Neil. This issue has been fixed and an update was pushed out last week for the Cloud Code extension. Cloud Shell should be getting the update soon.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - I have not had this problem for the last couple of days

Comment: Thanks @MaratB - I will remember that for future reference. I use Cloud Shell a *lot* so get in contact with me if you need more in-depth information